# Nodemon fs.writeFileSync Crash

Tags: node.js, linux, fs, nodemon

I have a queue of data from the [AWS SQS service](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/), and I am retrieving this data, posting it to a webpage created and hosted via Node.js, and then telling the SQS service to delete the file. I use Nodemon to create and update the page, such that every time I pull a new event, the page updates and users logged into the page see fresh data. I achieve this with code that goes something like:

```
sqs.receiveMessage(data){
    if (data = 1) {
        dataForWebPage = something
        fs.writeFileSync( "dataFile.json", JSON.stringify(dataForWebPage, null, 2), "utf8");
    }
    if (data = 2) {
        dataForWebPage = somethingDifferent
        fs.writeFileSync( "dataFile.json", JSON.stringify(dataForWebPage, null, 2), "utf8");
    }
}

sqs.deleteMessage(data)
```

When testing this on Windows using Visual Code Studio, this works well. Running 'nodemon myscript.js' and opening localhost:3000 displays the page. As events come in, nodemon restarts, the page updates seamlessly, and the events are purged from the queue.

However, if zip the files and modules up, and move the script over to a linux machine, running an identical script via SSH means that I can view the webpage, the page gets update, nodemon restarts and behaves in the same way that I expect, but the messages from the SQS queue do not get deleted. They simply stay in the queue, and are never removed. Moments later, my script will pull them again, making the webpage inaccurate. They will continue to look forever and never delete.

If I do not use nodemon or if I comment out the fs.writeFileSync, the app works as expected and the events from the SQS queue are deleted as expected. However, my webpage is not then updated.

I had a theory that this was due to nodemon restarting the service, and as a result, causing the script to stop and restart before it reached the 'deleteMessage' part. However, If I simply move the delete event so that it happens before any reset, it does not solve the problem. For example, the following code is still broken on Linux, but like the previous version, DOES work on Windows:

```
sqs.receiveMessage(data){
    if (data = 1) {
        dataForWebPage = something
        sqs.deleteMessage(data)
        fs.writeFileSync( "dataFile.json", JSON.stringify(dataForWebPage, null, 2), "utf8");
    }
    if (data = 2) {
        dataForWebPage = somethingDifferent
        sqs.deleteMessage(data)
        fs.writeFileSync( "dataFile.json", JSON.stringify(dataForWebPage, null, 2), "utf8");
    }
}
```

It seems that if I use the asynchronous version of this call, fs.writeFile, the SQS events are also deleted as expected, but as I receive a lot of events, I am using the synchronous version of this service to ensure that data does not queue, and is updated simultaneously.

Later in the code, I use fs.readFileSync, and that does not seem to be interfering with the call to delete the SQS events.

My questions are:

1) What is happening, and why is it happening?

2) Why only Linux, and not windows?

3) What's the best way to solve this to ensure I get live updates to the page, but events are being deleted as expected?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What is happening, and why is it happening?

Guessing : `deleteMessage` is asynchronous, and a `sync` operation to write file is blocking the event loop, so your deleteMessage http call may be blocked and as you restart the process, it's actually never executed.

> 2) Why only Linux, and not windows?

No idea.

> 3) What's the best way to solve this to ensure I get live updates to
>   the page, but events are being deleted as expected?

I will be blunt : you have to redo all the architecture of your system. 
Voluntarily failing your webserver and restarting it to refresh a web page won't scale to more than one user, and not even one it seems. It's not meant to work that way.
Depending of the constraint of the system you are trying to build (scale, speed, etc..) many different solution can work.

To stay as simple as possible :

A first improvement could be to keep your file storage but expose it through an API to get the data on the frontend from an ajax request, and polling it at regular interval. You will have a lot more request, but a lot less problem. It's maybe less "live" but few system actually need less than a few seconds live update.

Secondly, don't do sync operation on nodejs, it's a huge performance bottleneck, leading to strange errors and huge latencies.

When that works, file storage is usually a pain, and not really performant, maybe ask yourself if you need a database or a memcached/redis, also you can check if you need to replace polling an API from the webpage to a Socket that will prevent a lot of request and allow less than 1sec update.